# how to delete a object in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

How to delete object in bucket  Exp `test.csv` before unload command execute.

UNLOAD ('select * from abc')
TO 's3://Bucket/Product/temp/test.csv' CREDENTIALS 
'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xx'PARALLEL OFF

Thanks

Comment: Elaborate your question more.

Answer (score 1):

By adding Adding this  **ESCAPE ALLOWOVERWRITE** I Got

UNLOAD ('select * from abc') TO 's3://Bucket/Product/temp/test.csv' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xx'PARALLEL OFF ESCAPE ALLOWOVERWRITE